# How to dynamically insert rows into a table

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-table, rows

I have a table with a table head and and empty body:

```
<table id ="floodTable" class ="gradient-style">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Event Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th style="text-align:right">Return Period</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
            ...//add stuff here...      
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have an API that brings in a JSON object. If one of the sub-objects meets a certain criteria, I want to use the attribute values to populate the new row with values for

"Event Name" (`document.getElementById("floodTable").rows[0].cells[1]`),
"Date" (`document.getElementById("floodTable").rows[0].cells[2]`), and
"Return Period" (`document.getElementById("floodTable").rows[0].cells[3]`)

Using that my API may pull back multiple items that meet my criteria, I will probably have to create several rows. How can I use `insertRow(0)` and/or `insertCell(0)` to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HTMLTableElement.insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) and [`HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) methods to achieve this:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  
  const values = Object.values(form.elements).filter(el => el.id).map(el => el.value); 
  if (values.length === 3) {
    const table = document.querySelector('#floodTable tbody');
    const row = table.insertRow(0);
  
    values.forEach((val, ind) => {
      row.insertCell(ind).innerHTML = val;
    });
    form.reset();
    window.location.href = '#floodTable';
  }
}, false);
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <table id="floodTable" class="table gradient-style">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Event Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th style="text-align:right">Return Period</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <div class="card">
    <form class="card-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="event">Event name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="event" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="period">Return period:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="period" required>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add a row</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Arghhh! Unfortunately, can't use the Bootstrap (interferes with existing css too much) but I was able to get a variation of this to work!